# Custom Cell Render JXtreetable

Tags: tablecellrenderer, jxtreetable

this is my first post, I'm actually implementing JXtreetable component, which I have managed to display all the data contained in it, but I want to create a custom cell rendering in order to display parent's row different with their child (i.e make the font to be bold), is there anyone that can help?
So far,I can only change column's render by using

```
myTreeTable.getColumn (int col). setCellRenderer (myRendererObj);
```

where I had made earlier myRendererObj,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setTreeCellRenderer(...)` method of `JXTreeTable`. You give it a `DefaultTreeRenderer` which you can then give a `ComponentProvider`. I subclassed `ComponentProvider` to do my custom tree cells.

Comment: thanks for your solution, but I still couldn't figure how it implemented,now I have some alternative solution in order to differentiate each children on my treetable, simply using  class 'ColorHighlighter'
'myTreeTable.setHighlighters(new ColorHighlighter(new DepthHighlightPredicate(int lvlChild), Color(background), Color(foreground)));'

Comment: The method I mentioned is useful if you need to dramatically change the components you want to render in the the tree. All of the classes I mentioned are in SwingX 1.6.3. The Javadoc is here: http://www.abusingjava.net/AbusingSwing/doc/SwingX-1.6.3/index.html?overview-summary.html